# TypeError: var_date.getFullYear is not a function, call getFullYear in a function

Tags: angularjs, function, date

I wrote a function to return first date unixtime of input date.

```
function firstDateOfMonth(var_date, month) {
    var tmp =(new Date(var_date.getFullYear(), month, 1, 0, 0, 
0).getTime() / 1000);
    return tmp;
  }
```

var_date is the date format select from calendar.

```
Sat Dec 22 2018 13:40:19
```

And got this error:

```
TypeError: var_date.getFullYear is not a function
```

I try to search here and most of answer said need keyword "new"

Comment: well, it is just what it says `getFullYear is not a function`, obviously `var_date` is not a `Date` object. The problem is not in the code you provided.

Comment: Here is a simple plunker example https://plnkr.co/edit/2P1ofRFGRdVctqWXhfjo?p=preview